# Biber and BibTeX not compatible

Tags: biber

Im trying to run my file and I keep getting the error:

ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.9) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.

I already tried downloading Biber from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/?source=typ_redirect I then put the biber file next to my tex document and it still gives the same error message.

I searched for Biber in the package manager and could not find it. How can I update my Biber to 2.9?

After trying to select all to update, the process won't work.

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: I recently had the same problem under MikTeX. Updating all packages using the MiKTeX Package Manager solved the problem for me.

Comment: Im on MiKTeX windows-64. I just reinstalled MiKTeX, updated the packages, and it still says that I have biber 2.7

Comment: When i selected all to update it said the process did not succeed

Comment: Did you synchronise the package repository you use? Present version is `2.9` and `biblatex` is in version `3.9`.

Comment: Under the package manager's repository tab I clicked synchronize, but after I checked the biber package and it still says 2.7